# Two Streams interfering in c

Tags: c, file-io, stream

The following code gives me a file with an "s" in it.

```
main () {
    FILE *ptr_TextOut;
    char character;

    // Open TextOut
    ptr_TextOut=fopen("/Users/jonathanclark/Software Projects/C/Baffle/TextOut","w");
    if (!ptr_TextOut)
    {
        printf("Unable to open TextOut!");
        return 1;
    }

    character = 's';

    fputs(&character, ptr_TextOut);
    fclose(ptr_TextOut);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when opening up a second stream as in the following code I get "sË–‚vˇ" in the file.

```
main () {
    FILE *ptr_TextOut;
    FILE *ptr_CodeIn;
    char character;

    // Open TextOut
    ptr_TextOut=fopen("/Users/jonathanclark/Software Projects/C/Baffle/TextOut","w");
    if (!ptr_TextOut)
    {
        printf("Unable to open TextOut!");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open CodeIn
    ptr_CodeIn=fopen("/Users/jonathanclark/Software Projects/C/Baffle/CodeIn","r");
    if (!ptr_CodeIn)
    {
        printf("Unable to open CodeIn!");
        return 1;
    }

    character = 's';

    fputs(&character, ptr_TextOut);
    fclose(ptr_TextOut);
    fclose(ptr_CodeIn);

    return 0;
}
```

Must I not have two streams open simultaneouly or is there some other mistake in my code? I would have expected an "s" in the file TextOut in both cases. I'm running my code on a MAC if that is relevant. I have tried deleting previous versions of the file TextOut before running again but get the same result. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `main ()` is an invalid signature!

Comment: How were you expecting `fputs` to know that you only wanted to output one character?

Comment: "Unable to open CodeIn!` sounds like an error.  Error messages belong on stderr.  `if(!ptr_CodeIN) { perror("/path"); return 1;)`

Comment: Don't forget to end messages with newlines.  Don't forget to write in modern C — that means you should explicitly specify the return type of every function, including `main()` (which should return an `int`).  You should use fussier compilation options, such as `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition …`.

Answer (score 1):

`fputs()` receive a null-terminated string, not a character unlike `fputc()`.

> In computer programming, a null-terminated string is a character string stored as an array containing the characters and terminated with a null character (`'\0'`, called NUL in ASCII).

You put a pointer to the character as a parameter, which does not have a null to terminate it, which leads to an undefined behavior.

> The function begins copying from the address specified (str) until it reaches the terminating null character ('\0'). This terminating null-character is not copied to the stream.

Replace `char character = 'c';` with `char* word = "c";`. This will use a pointer to a null-terminated string, instead of a char primitive.

Also, you will need to change the call to `fputs()` to:

```
fputs(word, ptr_TextOut); // No need to reference the input (&)
```

Or, just use `fputc(character, ptr_TextOut);`.

### Explaining Your Output

On the underlying memory structure of the executed program the variables are stored, possibly, one next to the other.
So if coincidently, the location of another variable was right after the character variable and had null in it, it would have effectively terminated the string.
This might have happened in the first program, but not in the second.

Comment: There is no stack in the C language.

Comment: @Olaf I could not explain the output he got without referring to the underlying memory structure of the program. I changed the answer, however, to better emphasize what he did wrong rather than the explanation of the output.

Comment: There is an obvious and compliant answer: undefined behaviour. No further research necessary, even more as we don't know the generated machine code (and it is irrelevant anyway). We don't evern know there is a stack used.

Comment: @Olaf From a "C" perspective you are correct. But realistically, I don't know of any other existing machine that runs compiled (**C**) code without a stack. I believe that if someone asked a question like this (obviously a fresh code enthusiastic), he/she should know what lead to this output.

Comment: 1) The question **is** about the C language. 2) You might want to widen your horizon. x86, ARM, MIPS, PPC and SPARC are a very minority of architectures (and magnitudes less of the devices sold). And even on these architectures an implementation might (and all modern do) choose not to use the stack for a lot of automatic variables. 3) I already said this, but mabe repetition helps: don't explain with a specific implementation if the standard is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Liran this answer has made me understand this. Thanks to all other comments also.